# Why without using action my form still stores data into database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

i'm thinking to insert catcha process into form so i'm thinking some logics, so i downloaded a login from google, but i don't understand here.. why my form still stores data into database using `action=' '` while it comes with `action="register.php"` but as i told you i'm doing some logics stuff so can you tell me what's wrong here?

here is my full code:

```
<?php
// show potential errors / feedback (from registration object)
if (isset($registration)) {
    if ($registration->errors) {
        foreach ($registration->errors as $error) {
            echo '<div class="alert-box error"><span>Error: </span>'.$error.'</div>';
        }
    }
    if ($registration->messages) {
        foreach ($registration->messages as $message) {
            echo '<div class="alert-box success"><span>Success: </span>'.$message.'</div>';
        }
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Registration with Linkvessel and collaborate with college's friends</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="./CSS_files/registration_style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" />
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                $("#datepicker").datepicker();
            });            
        </script>
        <style>
            .alert-box {
        color:#555;
        border-radius: 0px;
        font-family:Tahoma,Geneva,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:11px; font-size: 18px;
        padding:  30px 36px;
        margin:10px;
            }
            .alert-box span {
        font-weight:bold;
        text-transform:uppercase;
            }
            .error {
        border:2px solid #0c0b0b;
                background-color: #ff7e48;
            }

            .success{
            border:2px solid #0c0b0b;
            background-color: #a3ea42;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <img id="logo_size" src="./images/logo.png" onmousedown="return false">
        </div><br><br><br>

        <form id="form_box" method="post" action='' name="registerform">
                <div id="title">
                    <h2>REGISTRATION FORM</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="controls pos_selectbox">
                    <select id="basic" name="user_college" class="input-medium">
                        <option>Select College</option>
                        <option>MAIIT kota</option>
                    </select>&nbsp; &nbsp;

                    <select id="basic" name="user_branch" class="input-medium">
                        <option>Select Branch</option>
                        <option>Computer science</option>
                        <option>Civil</option>
                        <option>Mechanical</option>
                        <option>Electrical</option>
                        <option>Bioinformatic</option>
                    </select>&nbsp; &nbsp;

                    <select id="basic" name="user_year" class="input-medium">
                        <option>Select year</option>
                        <option>1st year</option>
                        <option>2nd year</option>
                        <option>3rd year</option>
                        <option>4th year</option>
                        <option>Year completed</option>
                    </select>&nbsp; &nbsp;
                </div><br>

                <input id="input_pos" type="email" name="user_email" required="" placeholder="Email address" /><br><br>

                <input id="input_pos" type="password" name="user_password_new" required="" placeholder="Password" /><br><br>

                <input id="input_pos" type="password" name="user_password_repeat" required="" placeholder="Confirm password" /><br><br>

                <input id="name_pos" type="text" name="user_firstname" required="" placeholder="First name" />&nbsp;

                <input id="name_pos2" type="text" name="user_lastname" required="" placeholder="Last name" /><br><br>

                <input id="datepicker" type="text" name="user_dob" required="" placeholder="Date of birth" /><br><br>

                <input id="name_pos" type="text" name="user_state" required="" placeholder="State" />&nbsp;

                <input id="name_pos2" type="text" name="user_city" required="" placeholder="city" />&nbsp;<br><br>

                <input type="submit" name="register" id="pos_submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" value="Create account.."/>
            </form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An empty value for the form action attribute defaults to the current URL. So if the URL for that page is `register.php`, `action=''` is the same as doing `action='register.php'`.

The [W3C spec says this behavior is unspecified](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html) but the browsers have universally implemented the above behavior.

> Finally, the encoded data is sent to the processing agent designated
>   by the action attribute using the protocol specified by the method
>   attribute.
>
> This specification does not specify all valid submission methods or
>   content types that may be used with forms. However, HTML 4 user agents
>   must support the established conventions in the following cases:
>
> - If the method is "get" and the action is an HTTP URI, the user agent
>     takes the value of action, appends a `?' to it, then appends the form
>     data set, encoded using the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
>     content type. The user agent then traverses the link to this URI. In
>     this scenario, form data are restricted to ASCII codes.
> - If the method is "post" and the action is an HTTP URI, the user agent
>     conducts an HTTP "post" transaction using the value of the action
>     attribute and a message created according to the content type
>     specified by the enctype attribute.
>
> For any other value of action or method, behavior is unspecified.

Comment: But i'm making some captcha stuff and my logics is if i use `action=''` in form then i'll use `header('Location: register.php');` in if-else condition in captcha i guess as you know ... now what should i suppose to do with this?? any idea..